# getchar and SIG34, the Real-time event 34

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, signals

I have a multi-threaded program. The main thread uses a getchar to close all the other threads and itself. I have a timer functionality used in one of the child threads. This thread uses SIG34 for timer expiration.

At some point, I receive the `SIG34` as below. **This is affecting the getchar in my main thread and my program just aborts.** Please help me in understanding the same.

```
Program received signal SIG34, Real-time event 34.
0x00007ffff6ea38cd in read () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff6ea38cd in read () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff6e37ff8 in _IO_file_underflow () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff6e3903e in _IO_default_uflow () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff6e2fb28 in getchar () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000000000401eef in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe178) at ../../src/SimMain.c:186
```

**Note:**

In the child thread, I have assigned SIGRTMIN(translates to SIG34 on my system) for timer signalling and have a handler also. This handler sets a global variable to let me change course post timer expiration. But unsure why getchar is in issue.

Timer Init and usage:

```
/* Timer macros */
     #define CLOCKID CLOCK_REALTIME
     #define SIGRT_OFFSET 4 // was 0 before, hence, SIG34, now it is SIG38

     #define SIG (SIGRTMIN + SIGRT_OFFSET)

    void cc_timer_init() 
{
    // Install the timer handler...

    struct sigevent sev;
    long long freq_nanosecs;
    struct sigaction disc_action;

    /* Establish timer_handler for timer signal */


    memset (&disc_action, 0, sizeof (disc_action));
    disc_action.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO; //0 before
    disc_action.sa_sigaction = disc_timer_handler;
    sigaction(SIG, &disc_action, NULL);
    myState = INIT_STATE;


    /* Create the timer */

    sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    sev.sigev_signo = SIG;
    sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &timerid;
    timer_create(CLOCKID, &sev, &timerid);


    /* Set itimerspec to start the timer */

    freq_nanosecs = TMR_TV_NSEC;
    v_itimerspec.it_value.tv_sec = TMR_TV_SEC;
    v_itimerspec.it_value.tv_nsec = freq_nanosecs % 1000000000;
    v_itimerspec.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    v_itimerspec.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;

}

static void disc_timer_handler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc)
{
    /* Global variable that I set */
    State = MID_1_STATE;
}

/* In another part...*/
.
.
.
case INIT_STATE :
    {
        v_itimerspec.it_value.tv_sec = TMR_TV_SEC;
        timer_settime(timerid, 0, &v_itimerspec, NULL);
        ret_val = SUCCESS;
    }
    break;
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Related (but unanswered): [Program terminating on receiving - signal SIG34, Real-time event 34](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6735791/464709).

Comment: Can you show the code that sets up the signal handler and timer ?

Comment: @nos timer create and signal handlers are shown

Comment: @Aad you might want SA_RESTART in disc_action.sa_flags, and/or you might try to mask the signal in all other threads (so the signal handler will only run in the thread where you create it - albeit that shouldn't cause the problems seen here)

Comment: The issue is with getchar as I see from the backtrace. Any comments on the angle where the signal may not be the culprit at all and something else is the issue?

Answer (score 3):

From the ubuntu pthreads information sheet (LinuxThreads)):

```
      In addition to the main (initial) thread, and the threads  that  the
      program  creates using pthread_create(3), the implementation creates
      a  "manager"  thread.   This  thread  handles  thread  creation  and
      termination.   (Problems  can result if this thread is inadvertently
      killed.)

   -  Signals are used internally by the implementation.  On Linux 2.2 and
      later,  the  first three real-time signals are used.
```

Other implementations use the first two RT signals.  Set SIGRTMIN above these two/three signals that used by threading management.  See what your pthreads(7) man page says about SIGRTMIN. And adjust accordingly.

Comment: The information you quote relates to LinuxThreads, not NTPL. LinuxThreads haven't been in use for quite a few years now.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. But that seems to be the issue, and the OP did not state the kernel release. That was the only explanation for a "spurious" RT signal, unless of course, his code generated it.  Thanks for the correction.  +1